# About separable spaces

Tags: real-analysis

Let $Y$ be the subspace of $B(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{F})$ which consist of all the sequences that tends to zero.
Prove that Y is separable.

We must show that exists $X\subset Y$ such that $X$ is countable and dense. It's useful define the set $Y_k=\lbrace(x_n)\in Y: x_n=ky_n, k\in\mathbb{Q} \rbrace$?

Comment: What does $B(\mathbb N, \mathbb F)$ mean?

Comment: @BolzWeir The bounded functions with terms in $\mathbb{F}$

Comment: What is $\mathbb F$?

Comment: I think that this problem appears in Runde, A taste of topology. Maybe $\mathbb{F}$ means a field?

Comment: Well...but then I'm not clear what "bounded" means.  Nor can I guess what $y_n$ means in the "usefully defined" set $Y_k$.    But, given that you can multiply by rationals, I guess $\mathbb F$ is a vector space over $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: If $\mathbb F=\mathbb C$ and $B(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{C})\subset l^\infty$, then the hint is basically the  answer.

Comment: If you look around in the book, you will almost certainly see somewhere that "$\Bbb F$" means "either $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$". I.e., the statement is true for both fields. This is a common shortcut authors use when they want to state theorems applicable to both.